# Calling a private/nested javascript function from an outer scope

Tags: javascript

I have my javascript code like this . Inside that I have an init() function and in that function I have an options JSON object and in that object I have a function defined as objectselected(). How I call that function in a button click event

I have tried like this WorkFlow.init().options.Objectselected() but it is not working,

```
var WorkFlow = {
connectionData: [],
    selectedTouchpoints: [],
    init: function () {
        var options = {
            palleteId: "myPaletteElement",
            elementId: "playAreaContainer",
            TextStoreList: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
            LinkTextStoreList: $('#drpLinkType option').map(function () {
                return this.text;
            }).get(),
            shapeList: ['RoundedRectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Ellipse', 'Square', 'Diamond', 'Card', 'Database'],
            diagramUpdate: function (e) {

            },
            objectSelected: function (e) {
            },

            linkUpdate: function (e) {

            },
            initialize: function () {

                }



        myGraph = new Graph(options);
        options.initialize();
    },
}
```

How to call that function.

Comment: Because `options` is a private variable in its scope, you don't have outside access to it. Note also this question has nothing to do with jQuery or JSON.

Comment: `init()` doesn't return anything, so you can't do `init().options`

Comment: you can't have a function in a json string

Comment: It's not a JSON string - the question was mistitled. It's straight-up JavaScript.

Comment: is there any way to call it

Comment: @Utpal: return `options` from `init()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `options` as it is inside init function's scope

```
var WorkFlow = {
    connectionData: [],
        selectedTouchpoints: [],
        init: function () {
            var options = {
                palleteId: "myPaletteElement",
                elementId: "playAreaContainer",
                TextStoreList: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
                LinkTextStoreList: $('#drpLinkType option').map(function () {
                    return this.text;
                }).get(),
                shapeList: ['RoundedRectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Ellipse', 'Square', 'Diamond', 'Card', 'Database'],
                diagramUpdate: function (e) {

                },
                objectSelected: function (e) {
                },

                linkUpdate: function (e) {

                },
                initialize: function () {

                }

            myGraph = new Graph(options);
            options.initialize();
            return options;
        },
    }
```

And call it as `WorkFlow.init().objectSelected();`

Comment: may I know the reason for -1

Comment: Hi @Utpal, please let me know if this works for you or not

Comment: I have not given u -1

Comment: Thanks @Utpal I know that.. Please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: The problem with your solution is that I have already called the init in my document.ready, so when I am calling it for the second time it is giving error as binding are there

Answer (score 0):

One way around is you can return options and than call it.

```
init: function () {
        var options = {
            ...your code..}
        return options;
    },
```

and call it than

```
var options = WorkFlow.init();
options.Objectselected();
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that I have already called the init in my document.ready, so when I am calling it for the second time it is giving error as binding are there

Answer (score 0):

Building on Patrick's comment, you'd need to return `options` from the `init` function:

```
var WorkFlow = {
connectionData: [],
    selectedTouchpoints: [],
    init: function () {
        var options = {
            palleteId: "myPaletteElement",

            ...    

        options.initialize();
        return options;            
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you have no access to `options` because it's a local variable - that is, local to its scope.

To access its contents, you'll need to return it from `init()`.

Think about it:

```
WorkFlow.init()
```

Currently this returns `undefined`, because your `init()` returns nothing. You're trying to chain like in jQuery, but that relies on the API always returning the instance. Your path finds a dead-end at `init()`.

To fix this, have `init()` return `options` - or at least the part of it you want to access from outside - an "export".

So (basic example)

```
init: function() {
    var options {
        my_func: function() { }, //<-- we want outside access to this
        private: 'blah' //<-- this can stay private - leave it out of the export
    }
    //return an export, exposing only what we need to
    return {
        my_func: options.my_func
    }
}
```